# Update Lowest grade variable with final exam score

Tags: sas

I have a xls file that I've imported in SAS Studio, it contains 76 observations (one for each student), with variables homework, 'final', 'exam1', 'exam2', 'exam3', and 'act'.  I want to write a SAS program that updates each student's lowest exam score (exam1, exam2 or exam3) with the value of their "final' grade.  How can I code this?

I know how to update variables with code, but I don't' know how to find the lowest grade and then update that variable

This is what my program looks like so far:

```
FILENAME FinalG '/home/mrohde0/MyFolder/HWData/HW6/FINAL Grade.xlsx';

/** Import the file.  **/

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE=FinalG
    OUT=WORK.MYFinalG
    DBMS=xlsx
    REPLACE;
RUN;

Data 
    proc print data=MyFinalG;

run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to my problem.  I posted it below.

```
data MyAdjGr; /* my adjusted grade */
    set work.MyFinalG;
    if exam1 = min(exam1, exam2, exam3) then exam1 = final;
    else if exam2 = min(exam1, exam2, exam3) then exam2 = final;
    else if exam3 = min(exam1, exam2, exam3) then exam3 = final;
run;
```

Comment: What happens all the exam marks are higher than the final mark?

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array for the exams and you can use WHICHN function to find index of the lowest score.  This is the same amount of code as above, so there is no difference in terms of length of code. It will scale better though, if you had to add 4 more exams, you'd need 4 more lines whereas the solution below would only require a change in one line, the array dimension and variable declaration.

```
data want;
set have; 
array exams(3) exam1 exam2 exam3;
lowest_index=whichn(min(of exams(*)), of exams(*));
exams(lowest_index) = final;
*if you want to conditionally assign the lowest value:;
*if final > exams(lowest_index) then exams(lowest_index)=final;
run;
```